# R barplot x-axis labels formatting

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot 50+ variables using a for-loop in R. As usual I'm fighting with R on the formatting details. In this case, it's the x-axis labels. When I place the labels that I want in vectors nested in a list and use that in the `names.arg` parameter of the barplot function as below,

```
x_axis_labels <- list(c("X1", "X2", "X3"),
                      c("X1", "X2"),
                      c("X1", "X2", "X3"),
                      c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"),
                      c("X1", "X2"),
                      c("X1", "X2", "X3"),
                      c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"),
                      c("X1", "X2")
                      )  

for (j in 1:8){        
    data <- df[order(df[, j]), j]        
    bp <- barplot(prop.table(table(data, useNA = "ifany")),
            main = "title",
            xlab = colnames(data),
            ylab = "Frequency",
            col = "gray",
            names.arg = x_axis_labels[j],
            ylim=c(0,1))
        text(x = bp, y = as.factor(data) + 0.5, labels = names(data))
  }
```

I get the following:

[image]

However, when I place the vector in the same code, as below,

```
j <- 1

data <- df[order(df[, j]), j]bp <- barplot(prop.table(table(data, useNA = "ifany")),
            main = "title",
            xlab = colnames(data),
            ylab = "Frequency",
            col = "gray",
            names.arg = c("X1", "X2", "X3"),
            ylim=c(0,1))
        text(x = bp, y = as.factor(data) + 0.5, labels = names(data))
```

It does it correctly,

[image]

How do I get the x-axis labels correctly as in the second image but using the for-loop in the first chunk of code?

```
df <- data.frame(
Var1 = ("X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X1", "X3", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X3", "X1", "X1", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X2"), 
Var2 = ("X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1"), 
Var3 = ("X1", "X3", "X2", "X3", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X3", "X1", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X3", "X1", "X3", "X3", "X3"), 
Var4 = ("X2", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X4", "X2", "X1", "X4", "X4", "X2", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X4", "X3", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X4", "X3"), 
Var5 = ("X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X1"), 
Var6 = ("X3", "X2", "X1", "X3", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X3", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2"), 
Var7 = ("X2", "X3", "X4", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X3", "X2", "X4", "X3", "X2", "X1", "X4", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X1", "X3", "X2", "X1", "X4"), 
Var8 = ("X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X2")
)
```

Comment: `names.arg = x_axis_labels[[j]]` should do the trick. When indexing a list and you want to get the list element you need double brackets `[[...]]` instead of single brackets `[...]`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!